# How to use XCUIKeyboardKey constants?

Tags: ios, swift2, xcode-ui-testing

Just below the `XCUIElementQuery` class inside `XCTest` there are many constants where the documentation note above it states:

```
    Constants for use with -[XCUIElement typeKey:modifierFlags:],
    representing keys that have no textual representation. These comprise
    the set of control, function, and modifier keys found on most keyboards.
```

Apparently, it seems there should be a `XCUIElement` method called `typeKey:modifierFlags:`, as the note states. However, I can't seem to find this method anywhere in the documentation. I also don't see any method that substitutes this behavior, utilizing the aforementioned constants. Here is a partial list of the constants I'd be interested in using:

```
let XCUIKeyboardKeyDelete: String
let XCUIKeyboardKeyReturn: String
let XCUIKeyboardKeyTab: String
let XCUIKeyboardKeyCommand: String
```

Is this code just premature and will likely be completed later, as part of future Xcode 7 releases?

Ultimately, I'd like to be able to type `cmd+a` then use `XCUIKeyboardKeyDelete` to delete the contents of the given `XCUIElement`. If there are good alternatives currently available in Xcode 7 UI Testing, I'd love to learn know.

--> Swift 2.0 beta 4

Comment: I think `[XCUIElement typeKey:modifierFlags:]` got removed by accident or something on beta 4. The recorder uses it but it doesn't compile.

Comment: Good thought. I also have beta 3 installed, however, and I can't seem to find it there either. Any other ideas?

Comment: Nope... I submitted a radar.

Comment: Good idea, I'd definitely like to have that functionality. Hopefully they decide to implement it.

Comment: I also tried performSelector: on it and it doesn't seem to exist.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You can use XCUIElement.typeText(text: String) with XCUIKeyboardKeyDelete.

Example, when a text field is not empty:

```
textField.tapWithNumberOfTaps(2, numberOfTouches: 1)
app.menuItems["Select All"].tap()
textField.typeText(XCUIKeyboardKeyDelete)
```

Comment: This is a great idea and almost worked for me. tapWithNumberOfTaps only selected 1 character and XCUIKeyboardKeyDelete added a special character that didn't leave the field empty. Good stuff though

Answer (score 2):

It states in the documentation that the method `[XCUIElement typeKey:modifierFlags:]` is available on macOS only. See https://developer.apple.com/reference/xctest/xcuielement

I tested this out on Xcode 8.2.1 in a dummy macOS project UI Testing target, and indeed the method is existing. It does not exist on iOS.